Aliens take shelter in an African American house
I saw this movie around 1991. But the movie is probably made in the mid 80s. Hollywood movie.
The plot revolves around several aliens (in the form of a small space ships, the size of a baseball approx.)
I can't remember much of the plot, but the majority of the time, we see them inside the house of an African American family.
I distinctly remember one seen where one of these alien ships interacts with a large box of Tide soap.
If I'm not wrong, the aliens look alike each other, except: each alien has a different blinking light (green, blue, red, etc.)
I can't tell how many but they can't be more than 5.
I don't even remember who is the villain, or what are they afraid of, or how do they return "home".

*batteries not included sounds like it nearly matches, but not quite. The tenement has people of several ethnicities, but the aliens mainly live with a white family

*batteries not included sounds like it nearly matches, but not quite. The tenement has people of several ethnicities, but the aliens mainly live with a white family.
The plot revolves around an old tenement building whose residents don't wish to leave their homes, whilst 'big bad multinational' type company wants to knock down their building to re-use the land for their own gain.  The aliens help prevent that happening.



I can't find any specific interaction pictures with the soap powder, though I do vaguely recall it too.
